# Detect elements with same background-image value and remove

Tags: php, jquery, duplicates, background-image

I'm displaying a feed of posts some of those are using the same background image. I would like to find and hide the duplicate ones.

FULL CODE:

```
 <?php 
    $args=array(
                'cat' => '1',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'taxonomy' => 'postkicker',
                'term' => 'vote',
                'orderby'    => 'date',
                'order'      => 'DESC'
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();  

   $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),  array( 284,110 ), false, ''  );

 ?>

    <div class="divider-left">
     <a class="img-thumbnew" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
     <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> );"></div>
     </a>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing where the looping is happening.  But a poor man's answer here is to keep track of the src's seen in a loop and then abort when one is found

```
<?php
   $srcs_seen = array();
   while ( // looping over stuff ) {

       $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
           get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),  array( 284,110 ), false, ''  
       );

       // keep looping but stop here if we've seen it
       if (in_array($src['url'], $srcs_seen)) continue; 
       $srcs_seen[] = $src['url'];

       // print html like you were doing
   }
?>
```